# How do I avoid duplicate rows for create (POST) in Django-Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying avoid duplicate insertion of a row in django-tastypie model?  I see how I can do unique on a given field, but now how to ensure the entire create/post is unique.  I noticed there is a way to do it with django-piston within a handler class as follows:

```
def create(self,request):
        attrs = self.flatten_dict(request.POST)
        try:
            inst = self.model.objects.get(**attrs)
            return rc.DUPLICATE_ENTRY
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            inst = self.model(**attrs)
            inst.save()
            return inst
        except self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return rc.DUPLICATE_ENTRY
```

Let me know if I just didn't find an answer somewhere, I'd like to be able to post files that may have duplicate rows (such as bank transaction files with overlapping time periods).